# MS Access Letter Generator

Tags: ms-access

I have a number of letter templates which I want to populate with data from my MS Access database and am unsure how to go about it.

The way I want it to work is as follows:

- User is viewing a record within MS Access;
- User presses "Generate Letter" button;
- Choice of .doc/.docx templates (which I already have) appears;
- User selects template and presses 'OK';
- Letter is generated and populated with data from active record;
- Once user is finished with letter, pressing 'Save' will attach it to active record;
- (Ideally) any generated letters will appear within the attachments of each record (I have already created the attachments section - this is just for context)

How do I go about achieving this in MS Access 2013?  I cannot seem to figure out nor find anything which deals with this specific problem.

Comment: Look at a combo for the template and either bookmarks in the word document or mailmerge. I suggest saving to a temp file and mailmerge. There are quite a few aricles available, eg http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=3237

Answer (score 0):

The "Generate Letter" button should produce a pop-up form.  That form will have either a combobox or listbox (depending on what you see fit) that displays the list of available templates, as well as an "OK" button.

Alternatively, you can place the combobox/listbox on the main form and the "Generate letter" button next to it, assuming your main form has a subform that's displaying the data.

You will then do a Mail Merge with only the active record.  Once that's done, the most difficult part will be storing the "Save To" path in one of the fields.  You could possibly use an OLE field, but saving the path to the file is my preferred method.  I say it's the most difficult part because I'm not sure how you can capture that without using a standard dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

For the word merge and selection of a template, try my super easy word merge example here:

The sample I have can be found here:
http://www.kallal.ca/msaccess/msaccess.html

Above sample is specially designed to enable ANY form with ONE LINE of code.

Thus, each time you build a new form, you can word merge enable it with great ease. (with one line of code).

Make sure you read the instructions from above, and you should eventually get to the following page
http://www.kallal.ca/wordmerge/page2.html

The above handles all of your issues a requests with the exception of the last step in which you save the path name to the document (and I recommend you don’t save the document in the database – but only path names to a folder). Grabbing the file name is also possible with my sample.